# What is the proper way to implement async typeahead search?

Tags: angular, angular-http, angular2-observables, angular2-ngmodel

In my Angular app, there is a page of "Listings". Since there are hundreds of listings, the results only load 20 at a time and more are loaded when the user scrolls to the bottom and clicks <kbd>More</kbd>.

I want to put a search box above the listings that could send a more specific search term to the server to only return listings that match.

For example, when the user enters "myterm" into the search box, Angular should send a `GET` to `https://myapp.com/listings/?search=myterm` and display only those results on the "**Listings**" page.

I am not sure what the proper way to do this in Angular 2+ is. In AngularJS I would have simple fired a new request returning a promise everytime <kbd>Search</kbd> was pressed, but I suspect Angular2+ has a different approach. I just can't seem to find any literature about it.

So far I've just got the initial function call in the component that calls the service with an empty search parameter (aka, get everything)

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.listings = this.listingService.getListings('');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using ReactiveFormsModule since it'll be really easy to solve this issue.

First, let's define our FormGroup, which will consist of a single form control.

```
form: FormGroup;

constructor(formBuilder: FormBuilder){
    this.form = formBuilder.group({
        search: ''
    });
}
```

Now that we've defined our simple form, what we're interested in is sending a request as the user types, so basically whenever the value of our form control has changed. We can subscribe to the `valueChanges` Observable like this:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.form.get('search').valueChanges
       .subscribe(value => this.listingService.getListings(value)));
}
```

This clearly works, but the problem with this is that we don't want to send a request for every single character the user types. We want to wait until he's done. We can fix that by using the `debounceTime` operator:

```
this.form.get('search').valueChanges
       .debounceTime(1000)
       .subscribe(value => this.listingService.getListings(value)));
```

We also use [`switchMap`](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/http/search_with_switchmap.html) operator to avoid having to make a chain of subscriptions (since `getListings` also returns an observable).  The last thing we need to do is add a filter because we don't want to send a request with an empty string, assuming the user deletes everything typed. And we've got the `filter` operator for that:

```
this.form.get('search').valueChanges
       .filter(value => value)
       .debounceTime(1000)
       .switchMap(value => this.listingService.getListings(value))
       .subscribe(listings => this.listings = listings);
```

Template should be similar to this:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <input type="text" formControlName="search">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you tell me though, how do I get the value of the `getListings` function into the property `listings` so it can be displayed on the page. Note, that `getListings` calls the server, and thus returns an Observable too

Comment: And, how do I present this form in the view?

Comment: I edited my answer. I assumed you were familiar with these concepts, so my bad. Anyway, I suggest you read the docs to understand better what's going on and so that you also import everything correctly.

Comment: @CodyBugstein, basically valueChanges is an observable which we need to subscribe to, and your service also returns an Observable which also needs to be subscribed. So, to avoid having to make a chain of subscriptions, we use the switchMap operator which will return the Observable from your service and we subscribe only once.

Comment: Ok cool! Awesome! Just got it working!
The trickiest part was figuring out how to import the necessary modules/components. In the end I needed `ReactiveFormsModule` at the module level, and `import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';` in my component. I ended up doing `new FormGroup` since `formBuilder.group` was causing errors

Comment: @CodyBugstein, you really should avoid doing it that way. The FormBuilder class was added to be able to easily create FormGroup, FormControls and FormArrays. You would've also needed to import FormBuilder from @angular/forms, that was most likely the issue. But I definitely advise you don't create your own FormControls, and instead rely on the FormBuilder class to do it for you.